# Inserting values in a table in FOR loop statement in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to run the loop from i=1 to i=12 and insert each value of M_1,M_2 and so on till M_12 in M_Maintenance  table.I have tried but it is not working.Please help me out.
The code which I have tried is:-

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 12
   LOOP
      DECLARE
         M_i               NUMBER;
         MONTH_i_COUNT     NUMBER;
         M_i_Maintenance   NUMBER;
         MONTH_i_SUM       NUMBER;
      BEGIN
         SELECT   ROUND (
                     ( ( (SELECT   SUM (MONTH_i_COUNT)
                            FROM   XXBAXY.XXBAXY_BREAKDOWN_TAB
                           WHERE   LOSS_CAT = 'Maintenance Related Losses')
                        + (SELECT   MONTH_i_COUNT
                             FROM   XXBAXY.XXBAXY_BREAKDOWN_TAB
                            WHERE   LOSS_CAT = 'Maintenance Related Losses'
                                    AND description = 'SAFTY SHEET PRO. ')
                        - (SELECT   MONTH_i_COUNT
                             FROM   XXBAXY.XXBAXY_BREAKDOWN_TAB
                            WHERE   LOSS_CAT = 'Maintenance Related Losses'
                                    AND description =
                                          'PREVENTIVE MAINTENANCE '))
                      / (SELECT   MONTH_i_SUM FROM XXBAXY.XXBAXY_ATTR_SUM_TAB))
                     * 100,
                     3
                  )
           INTO   M_i
           FROM   DUAL;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE
         THEN
            M_i := 0;
      END;
      INSERT INTO M_Maintenance (M_i_Maintenance)
        VALUES   (M_i);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Can you better describe what "not working" means? Doesn't it compile? Does it throw an error during execution? Doesn't it insert any data? Is the inserted data incorrect? What messages are you getting?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to do this sort of thing

Comment: @DavidFaber Why would you need dynamic SQL for this? I'd rather say it can be done with a single INSERT statement.

Comment: @Codo-It is not inserting any data.It is throwing an error.                 ORA-06550: line 35, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 34, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: I meant dynamic SQL to loop over a set of numbers and generate column names dynamically. I agree that this particular problem does not seem to require dynamic SQL.

Comment: `SELECT   MONTH_i_SUM FROM XXBAXY.XXBAXY_ATTR_SUM_TAB` Check this statement. Is `MONTH_i_SUM` a column in XXBAXY.XXBAXY_ATTR_SUM_TAB?

Comment: The problem is that the INSERT statement refers to the variable `M_i`, which no longer exists at that point. It goes out of scope at the `END` statement on the previous line. A quick fix is to add another pair of BEGIN/END around the part the handles the exception.

Comment: BTW: You have two variables that have the same name as a column (at least it seems so). That's asking for trouble.

Comment: MONTH_1_SUM,MONTH_2_SUM and so on are columns in  XXBAXY.XXBAXY_ATTR_SUM_TAB

Comment: Very strange do have a `DECLARE` block after `BEGIN`. Did not even know that this is possible.

Comment: @Codo-I inserted the statement in the exception handling part also.Then it is throwing an error : data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Comment: IF I remove the insert statement then the code is working fine.But my requirement is to insert data in that table

Answer (score 1):

Let's first make your query easier to read and better perfoming, if I don't mistake it should be this one:

```
SELECT ROUND(
    SUM(CASE description
    WHEN 'SAFTY SHEET PRO. ' THEN 2*MONTH_i_COUNT
    WHEN 'PREVENTIVE MAINTENANCE ' THEN -MONTH_i_COUNT
    ELSE MONTH_i_COUNT
    END) / MIN(MONTH_i_SUM) *100, 3)
FROM XXBAXY.XXBAXY_BREAKDOWN_TAB
    CROSS JOIN XXBAXY.XXBAXY_ATTR_SUM_TAB 
WHERE LOSS_CAT = 'Maintenance Related Losses'
```

In this case your PL/SQL code can look like this (skipping the exception handler):

```
DECLARE
    m NUMBER;
    sqlstr VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..12 LOOP           
        sqlstr := 
        'SELECT ROUND( '
        '   SUM(CASE description '
        '   WHEN ''SAFTY SHEET PRO. '' THEN 2*MONTH_'||i||'_COUNT '
        '   WHEN ''PREVENTIVE MAINTENANCE '' THEN -MONTH_'||i||'_COUNT '
        '   ELSE MONTH_'||i||'_COUNT '
        '   END) / MIN(MONTH_'||i||'_SUM) *100, 3) '
        'FROM XXBAXY.XXBAXY_BREAKDOWN_TAB '
        '   CROSS JOIN XXBAXY.XXBAXY_ATTR_SUM_TAB ' 
        'WHERE LOSS_CAT = ''Maintenance Related Losses''';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr INTO m;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO M_Maintenance (M_'||i||'_Maintenance) VALUES (:m)' USING m;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @Wernfried-Thank you.But the query I think is different from mine.The output is not matching.

Comment: OK, but I assume you get the idea how to write the PL/SQL code

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean, that your table XXBAXY.XXBAXY_BREAKDOWN_TAB contains fields MONTH_1_COUNT, MONTH_2_COUNT, MONTH_3_COUNT and so on? If so, first step should be is redesigning this table because of violation of [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms). It's bad design, a way of immutable pain. If no, it's unclear why you try to use uninitialized local varables in SQL statement without any field references.

Generally it looks that you should avoid a FOR LOOP and PL/SQL and write a single insert/select statement which will produces all rows required.

Elaborating: your source has a common structure of

```
begin
  for i in MIN..MAX loop
    select something into value 
      from table1 
      where some_condition 
      and id = i;
    insert into table2 values (value);
  end loop;
end;
```

Almost always better way is do this as

```
insert into table2
  select something
  from table1
  where some_condition
  and id in (MIN..MAX);
```

Comment: -Please eleborate.I didnt get you or please provide me the code as per your understanding.

Comment: I agree to "first step should be is redesigning this table", but perhaps the OP cannot do this because of external constraints.

Comment: Maybe. But it's much better for him and future readers to say it explicitly.